# swt layouts position size

Tags: layout, swt, rcp

Please, I need your help. Excuse my poor english! I hope to be clear...I have a view for showing reports and charts but I'm stucked with the position and sizing of the elements. I read all about layouts and I can´t reach the goal. I attach an image with the position of the elements, so if you could help me telling me which types of layouts and layouts data I should use for each widget, I will appreciate your help. I tried everything: gridLayout, FormLayout...etc and tried a lot of options like numColumns, GridData,FormData, etc but it´s impossible! 
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: are you using window builder tool ?

Comment: Hi ranjeetcao! I solved the question implementing FormLayout and FormData, I dont know if its ok but it´s working and unfortunately nobody answered my question! :-(

Comment: There are few ways to arrange UI components using different layout, as a beginner it happened to me as well some time back, if your UI components are behaving proper on resize/different resolution then your implementation is okay, have faith in you :)

Comment: hehe, yes, That was my problem with first try, when I used different resolution, everything was awful!!! now it´s ok so I don´t touch it anymore jeje thanks!!